# How to get the current position of physical mouse connected with iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, mouse

I have an iOS app which requires the current position of the physical mouse connected with device using USB or Bluetooth. I want to get the global current position of the mouse i.e in context of device rather than app. I am able to get the position in respect to app using hover gesture recogniser but not sure how to achieve this for device context.

Anyone can help?

Comment: What do you mean by 'device context'? You want to get the position of mouse in the **screen** coordinates OR what?

Comment: Yes, but I need the coordinates even if the app is in background.